# Airflow s3Hook - read files in s3 with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, airflow

I'm trying to read some files with pandas using the `s3Hook` to get the keys. I'm able to get the keys, however I'm not sure how to get pandas to find the files, when I run the below I get:

> No such file or directory:

Here is my code:

```
def transform_pages(company, **context):
    ds = context.get("execution_date").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    s3 = S3Hook('aws_default')
    s3_conn = s3.get_conn()
    keys = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=Variable.get('s3_bucket'),
                        prefix=f'S/{company}/pages/date={ds}/',
                        delimiter="/")

    prefix = f'S/{company}/pages/date={ds}/'
    logging.info(f'keys from function: {keys}')

    """ transforming pages and loading data back to S3 """
    for file in keys:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are looking for is the following:

```
filepath = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{key}"
```

So in your specific case, something like:

```
for file in keys:
    filepath = f"s3://s3_bucket/{file}"
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

Just make sure you have `s3fs` installed though (`pip install s3fs`).

Comment: thanks! but I'm seeing the error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied.
seems someone else had this issue too: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27528

Comment: I am facing below exception , I am able to list the files in given directory but while reading in pandas getting `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials` and `FileNotFoundError: The specified bucket does not exist`